# Php convert string representation to correct type

Tags: php, casting

For example, I have a list of strings like this `["889003521", "level5", "120", "1.1", "500", "10", "false"]` and I need convert each element to real type, like this `[889003521. "level5", 120, 1.1, 500, 10, false]`, what is the best way to achive this? Thanks.

**Updated:** 
@04FS I found a way to make a conversion for int/float, not sure if it's the best way

```
      if (is_numeric($value)) {
            $floatVal = floatval($value);

            if($floatVal && intval($floatVal) != $floatVal){
                return $floatVal;
            }

            return (int)$value;
        }
```

but not sure how to convert to boolean.

Comment: If you explicitly need an `int` data type for the integers, that should be one possible way to do it. Translating `"false"` to `false` is something you will have to do “manually” though, because if you just cast it to `boolean`, the result would be `true`, because PHP considers any non-empty string that is not `0` as truth-y.

Comment: right, I made it like `    if ($value === 'false') {
            return false;
        }

        if ($value === 'true') {
            return true;
        }`. But I thought maybe there is a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use json_decode for that. Please bear in mind that for string it can return null when decoding, so we're checking whether the converted value is not null.

```
        $arr = ["889003521", "level5", "120", "1.1", "500", "10", "false"];
        $ret = [];

        foreach($arr as $val) {
            $converted = \json_decode($val);
            $ret[] = $converted ?? $val;
        }
```

And this is the content of the $ret array:

```
0 = {int} 889003521
1 = "level5"
2 = {int} 120
3 = {float} 1.1
4 = {int} 500
5 = {int} 10
6 = false
```

Answer (score 0):

in addition to tomfor's answer (thanks for that), here is a recursive function to set the correct type for associative arrays / json objects:

```
function convertType($obj) {
    if (gettype($obj) == 'array') {
        foreach ($obj as $k => $v) {
            $obj[$k] = convertType($v);
        }

        return $obj;
    }

    $converted = \json_decode($obj);
    return $converted ?? $obj;
}
```

u can use it like this:

```
$jsonWithCorrectTypes = convertType($someJson);
```